# Bootstrap JS validator and form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using this Bootstrap validator **github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator** for my bootstrap forms but it appears there is no way to set some external JS conditional before submitting forms.

For example, I would like to do the following from an external JS files:

1 # if form or some input of the form is invalid using validator() then I do some action.

2 # else Users will see some bootstrap button loading message until everything is submitted into the databases.

You can have a single case here:

```
$('button[data-loading-text]').click(function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.button('loading');
    $.blockUI();

 // #1 if form is invalid using validator() then I unblock the please wait message $.unblockUI(); and reset the bootstrap loading button.
 // #2 else users will still see the "please wait" message + bootsrap loading button untill everything is submitted into the databases.
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/temgo/k07nx06k/12/

Any help will be appreciated as it appears the plugin events are only set for specific field not for full form validation.

Regards

Comment: Did you check the docs? http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-events

Comment: Yes I have seen that and have tried but it only check for the first click and next users click are not working. Like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/temgo/k07nx06k/13/

Answer (score 5):

Check out the **Events** section on 1000hz page. (http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-events)

If you want to fire up the action before validating - just listen to the event.

```
$('#someFormId').on('validate.bs.validator', function(){
    doSomeStuff();
});
```

**Edit**

The problem with events is that it is fired after every field. From what I know this plugin doesn't provide an event for finished successful validation.

Comment: Yes I have seen that and have tried but it only check for the first click and next users click are not working. Like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/temgo/k07nx06k/13/

Comment: That is where my problem is. It is fired on every after every field and there is no way for now to control the successful finished validation. Maybe any other help can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

For your [ref](http://jsfiddle.net/ParthAkbari/5WMff/685/) hope it will help u

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('#contact-form').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        message: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
    },
    success: function (element) {
        element.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
            .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('Done');
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Thanks for this but this is a different jquery plugin

Comment: Check this [Ref](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/04/bootstrap-registration-form-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question looking for something else, but I have worked on precisely what you're trying to achieve.

My solution was to use the snippet of code the plugin author gives for binding to the submit button

```
$('#form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
  if ( !e.isDefaultPrevented() ) {
    // put your conditional handling here. return true if you want to submit
    // return false if you do not want the form to submit
  }
});
```

Hope that helps someone out.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
     $("#myForm").validator();

     $("#myButton").click(function (e) {
         var validator = $("#myForm").data("bs.validator");
         validator.validate();

         if (!validator.hasErrors()) 
         {
              $("myForm").submit();
         } else 
         {
              ...
         }
     }
})
```

Hope with will help.

Comment: Tahnks Igor, it was exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I am working so much for a better coding with this form validator js plugin.

Follow my code and try yourself:

```
// Select every button with type submit under a form with data-toggle validator
$('form[data-toggle="validator"] button[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
    // Select the form that has this button
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    // Verify if the form is validated
    if (!form.data("bs.validator").validate().hasErrors()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Here go the trick! Fire a custom event to the form
        form.trigger('submitted');
    } else  {
        console.log('Form still not valid');
    }
});

// And in your separated script, do the following:
$('#contactForm').on('submitted', function() {
    // do anything here...
})
```

Consider the following HTML code:

```
<form id="contactForm" action="/contact/send" method="POST" data-toggle="validator" role="form">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="inputName" id="inputName" class="form-control" data-error="Your input has an invalid value"/>
        <span class="help-block with-errors"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use validated.bs.validator to hand the event in order to do something after validating the form.

Regards!